# How to write file with Dask?

Tags: python, dask

I am using Dask:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd  
dsk = dd.read_parquet('/tmp/parquet/f1.parquet')
```

and just need to write `dsk` to a TXT file (whole content).
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the `to_csv` method.

```
dsk.to_csv('/path/to/*.csv')
```

Comment: That does not work - gives errors `(result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)` etc..

Comment: I recommend that you produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: All I did was `dsk.to_csv('file.txt')` to get above error.